# Should i compile kernel for i7?

Tags: kernel

Is there a noticeable benefit in compiling for an intel i7 processor?  Or am I fine sticking with the install kernel.  If there are brnefits, please elaborate.

Comment: It'll test if your system can build software...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have no real benefits of re-building a kernel, unless there are patches in a newer kernel version which are needed for your hardware, that aren't included in the version you have installed. But in general, there is no good reason to recompile a kernel from what is shipped in the distro.

Comment: That's where i was leaning, but i've seen several postings on how-to that i was curious if there was a true benefit.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: See also - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Answer (score 0):

For x86 architectures the kernel provides some CPU specific processor family options, for example for 64 bit builds it provides:

- Opteron/Athlon64/Hammer/K8
- Intel P4 / older Netburst based Xeon
- Core 2/newer Xeon
- Intel Atom
- Generic-x86-64

..so one can select the more appropriate build option if you so desire. For ubuntu, the kernel team uses the generic option.

It also depends on which version of GCC you use to build the kernel.  Newer versions of GCC should in theory produce better code than older versions but your mileage may vary.